# google maps flutter display data on the side

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I need to display the data for google maps on the side of the screen, the info I need is the waypoints already shown in google like in the image, I need to display the info from the waypoints on the screen on the side. Is there any way to work this out? [image: Image shows the waypoints and the display to the side]

Comment: Store all data in some kind of object oriented structure and as soon you get data from google maps populate the structure and use state management to render the side widget

Comment: yes I thought of that, but where do I get that data? which function gives me the data that comes with the API?

Comment: Google map provide you only the coordinates you need to call separate API's to fetch more information about the coordinates such as (Location name, postal code etc.) this will help https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete (requires you to enable google billings)